Why does the OCaml function `read_line` have type `unit -> string`?
I understand that its return type is the string that is read but why does it need the parameter of type unit?

Every OCaml function takes one value and returns one value. Since there are no meaningful values that read_line could take but it must take something, unit is provided.
And read_line must be a function, because some work has to be done when it's called.
Likewise, a function which performs an action but for which there is no meaningful return value typically returns unit in OCaml.
E.g.
# print_endline "Hello, world!";;
Hello, world!
- : unit = ()

